# cxFilterControl getting Filtertext inside in a component

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe

I have cxFilterControl what I felt with TCollectionItems (TableCollection - Field(Items). For example... Persons Table -> Person_ID, Age, Name etc...

What I need to do...
To save TcxFilterControl. FilterText to string to work with them after

I can get FilterTextSample: = cxFilterControl1.FilterText easily outside the component but generally the condition is setted by the user. I need the FilterText inside a Component

What I did...

```
    TMySampleComp = class(TComponent, IcxFilterControl)
  private

    FCriteria: TcxFilterControlCriteria;
    function GetPropertiesClassFromFieldType(AFieldType: TFieldType): TcxCustomEditPropertiesClass;
  private

    function GetCaption(Index: Integer): string;
    function GetCount: Integer;
    function GetCriteria: TcxFilterCriteria;
    function GetItemLink(Index: Integer): TObject;
    function GetItemLinkID(Index: Integer): Integer;
    function GetItemLinkName(Index: Integer): string;
    function GetProperties(Index: Integer): TcxCustomEditProperties;
    function GetValueType(Index: Integer): TcxValueTypeClass;
  public
    property Captions[Index: Integer]: string read GetCaption;
    property Criteria: TcxFilterCriteria read GetCriteria;
    property ItemLinkNames[Index: Integer]: string read GetItemLinkName;
    property ItemLinkIDs[Index: Integer]: Integer read GetItemLinkID;
    property ItemLinks[Index: Integer]: TObject read GetItemLink;
    property Properties[Index: Integer]: TcxCustomEditProperties read     GetProperties;
    property ValueTypes[Index: Integer]: TcxValueTypeClass read GetValueType;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
  end;

     TField = class(TCollectionItem) 
  private
    FEditProperties: TcxCustomEditProperties;

    procedure CreateProperties;
    procedure DestroyProperties;
    procedure RecreateProperties;
    procedure SetFieldType(const Value: TFieldType);
  protected
    procedure SetIndex(Value: Integer); override;
    function GetDisplayName: string; override;
  public
    constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    property EditProperties: TcxCustomEditProperties read FEditProperties;
  published
  end;
```

Everything is ok, all the Items can be reach through the TcxFilterControl -> (FilterText). Anyone can give a little advice how canI get these text (for example ...  (PERSON_ID >= 12) inside a component? I need a function for it.

What I start:

```
    procedure TdafUniqueSQLGenerate.GetFilterChangeValue(Sender:
    TcxFilterCriteria;
     const AFilterText: string);
   var
     vFilterText: string;
     I: integer;
     J: integer;
   begin
     if Sender is TcxFilterCriteria then
     begin

     vFilterText := Sender.FilterText;
     vFilterText := StringReplace(vFilterText, '<> NULL', 'is not null',    [rfReplaceAll]);
     vFilterText := StringReplace(vFilterText, '= NULL', 'is null', [rfReplaceAll]);
     end
     else vFilterText := '';

     if not vFilterText.IsEmpty then
        begin
          for I := 0 to Tables.Items[i].Fields.Count -1 do
```

Thanks for the help and sorry for my Eng!

Comment: Can you make me a small example showing your problem. The code you posted here can not compile.